# Castle Windsor + ISubDependencyResolver: weird issues

Tags: castle-windsor, castle

Castle Windsor 2.5. This fails. Why? Is it designated beahvior or a bug? Seems sub  dependency resolvers are not even queried when resolving top-level services.

```
class Program
 {
  class Resolver :ISubDependencyResolver
  {
   public object Resolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
   {
    return new Program();
   }

   public bool CanResolve(CreationContext context, ISubDependencyResolver contextHandlerResolver, ComponentModel model, DependencyModel dependency)
   {
    return dependency.TargetType == typeof (Program);
   }
  }

  [STAThread]
  static void Main()
  {
   var container = new WindsorContainer();
   container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new Resolver());
   var xxx = container.Resolve<Program>();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are sub **dependency** resolvers. They resolve dependencies, not root services. What are you really trying to do? Why not register the object upfront?

Comment: Problem actually solved (used UsingFactoryMethod instead ISubDependencyResolver)

I had session resolver to inject NHibernate session in my MVC-controllers. But then I wanted to implement an utility to inject dependencies (e.g. sessions) to my action filters. That requires direct resolving because I do sth like InjectProperties there.